# jQuery autocomplete: matchSubset option issue

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a text box with autocomplete set and working perfectly fine. However when I try to use the matchSubset option it throws an error in autocomplete.js file at

```
if (!options.matchCase)
    s = s.toLowerCase();
var i = s.indexOf(sub);
```

in the matchSubset function. It gives 'Object does not support this property or method' error. Below is my autocomplete code:

```
$('#txtUsers')
    .autocomplete("AjaxHandler.asmx/GetUserData", {
        width: 320,
        max: 10,
        minChars: 3,
        matchSubset: true,
        formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {
            return value.FullName + " (" + value.DepartmentName + ")";
        },
        parse: function(data) {
            var items = eval($(data).text());
            return $.map(items, function(row, i) {
                return {
                    data: row,
                    value: row,
                    result: row
                }
            });
        }
    })
    .result(function(event, data, formatted, text) {
        if (data) {
            $(this).val(data[0].FullName);
        }
    });
```

The very first time I type 3 chars, it works fine. However when I type my 4th char, it gives me the above mentioned error. Is it that I am doing some mistake in parsing my data? I had to evaluate the data in parse function, because my web service is giving me wrapped data. If I remove matchSubset option, the code just works fine but will query the server every time. Any help?

---

UPDATE: I think the issue is with my parse function. In the above code in matchSubset function, 's' is expected to be a string value where-as for me its an object containing multiple values like FullName , DepartmentName etc. How can I change my parse function accordingly?

Comment: That line `var items = eval($(data).text());` looks kinda fishy :) Did you try checking what's in `data` just before you get the error? (because it seems the `s` in the function giving the error corresponds with the `value` in the result of your parse array-of-objects)

Comment: Well the $(data).text() is returning a json wrapped in a string. That is the reason I had to eval it to get object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess you should change your `value` to be a string (disclaimer: I don't really know how jQuery.autocomplete works, I just know this is how you could get a string at the correct location :) ). So, use something like:

```
value: row.FullName + " (" + row.DepartmentName + ")"
```

Also, check the `data` some more, maybe it tries to `eval` it twice?

Comment: Trying out your recommendations.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Issue was with the value being an object. I converted it to string and worked like a charm. Thanks once again.